# The action has not been invoked in h:commandButton

Tags: jsf, action, commandbutton

I'm facing a problem that the action in  is not invoked. Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="ConfigForm" onsubmit="waitForSubmit();">
<table  class="configtable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
    <td  class="configtd" style="padding-left:15px;;">
        <h:inputHidden id="packageMode" value="#{configBean.Config.isPackageMode}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="isArpEnableOld" value="#{configBean.isArpEnableOld}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="menuli" value="#{configBean.menuli}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="NetBusiness" value="#{configBean.hasNetBusiness}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="errorMsg" value="${text['ruijie.license.netbusiness'] }">
        <input type="hidden" name="other_tip" id="other_tip" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["certificate.other"]}'/>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="wirelessdevice_tip" id="wirelessdevice_tip" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["terminal.wirelessdevice"]}'/>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="configjs_tip1" id="configjs_tip1" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["configjs.tip1"]}'/>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="configjs_tip2" id="configjs_tip2" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["configjs.tip2"]}'/>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="pc_tip" id="pc_tip" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["terminal.pc"]}'/>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="config_reset" id="config_reset" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["config.reset"]}'/>" />

        <div id="otherconfigdiv" class="configdiv">
            <table id="otherconfigtable"  class="configtable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                ...

                <tr>
                    <td class="configlefttd ">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="configrighttd ">
                        <h:commandButton value="#{text['action.save']}"  action="#{configBean.update}" styleClass="btn" onclick="return check();" />
                                <span class="cmbtnspn10"></span>
                             <input type="button" value="${text['action.reset']}" class="btn" onclick="reset();" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

I had also tried other method in configBean also but they are all not work, tried to debug but the method have not called. In other page those method work just fine.

Here is the js code called in onclick:

```
var netBusiness = $("#configForm\\:netBusiness").attr("value");
    var isShowRgHall = $("#configForm\\:isShowRgHall")[0].checked;
    if(netBusiness == 'false' && isShowRgHall){
        var errorMsg = $("#errorMsg").attr("value");
        self.parent.$("#subframe").attr("src","../../webcontent/web/nocomponent.jsf?netbusinessmsg="+errorMsg+"&messagetype="+1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

I think there is no problem with this js. Had debug this and it return true but the action still not being invoked.

Stuck with this in two days. And now I have no idea why this happen.
Looking for help.

Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="config_reset" id="config_reset" value="<h:outputText value='#{text["config.reset"]}'/>" />` Are you SURE this is working???

Comment: Check for possible cause here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked. And always create an [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje: it works in JSP (in other words, OP is likely using ancient JSF 1.x).

Comment: @BalusC: I suspected that due to the ${ usage, but could not remember ever doing this myself long ago...

Comment: @Kukeltje: JSP didn't support deferred EL in template text, so this was really "the only way" in order to get `#{...}` to run. OP could altenatively just have used `${...}` instead without the need for a whole `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: In that time I mostly used `${...}`, so that explains it...